# docker healthcheck in config.v2.json

Tags: docker, containers

```
docker ps --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }}: Health={{ .State.Health.Status }}'
c1ab47fdc94858275e9327ce56d039010cb9db1eb7865e0917f3d8a74862367e: Health=unhealthy
**Template parsing error: template: :1:27: executing "" at <.State.Health.Status>: map has no entry for key "Health"**
```

I just want to know why the error `map has no entry for key "Health` is reported after `docker inspect` command. The status should be in the container's `config.v2.json` file, however, in that file, there's no `unhealthy` under `Status`, so I want to know where is the "Health=unhealthy" come from.

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it seems docker doesn't even add the `Health` field in the `State` object if the container doesn't have a healthcheck.

Answer (score 0):

The ouput of command `docker inspect`, it shows the json as response.

If you notice the response, there is nothing called `Health`. Hence, the error. However, there is `State -> Status` whose value is `running`.  So just use `.State.Status` instead of `.State.Health.Status`

```
"State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 23570,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-10-30T07:06:14.114090476Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
```

Since you wanted to see Status, please use below command which shows as you desired output:

```
sudo docker ps --quiet | xargs sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }}:Health={{ .State.Status }}' 
5db8668eb121bd67b6fdeba12269fa7f194c48140b5d547c70befe70b2c3f607:Health=running
```

To show different `Status` value for another container which is not running any more shows as below :

```
$ sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }}:Health={{ .State.Status }}' 060d98f7838e
060d98f7838ec901fd7d3c855254af0d15702d2758d61f6754af8899bee9613a:Health=exited
```

Hope this is helpful.